# How to chain allow_any_instance_of with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, mocking

I'm in a bit of trouble in learning how rspec stub works.

I have to test the following helper method that I wish to test the output string as html:

```
def build_links(resource)
  YAML.load_file("config/admin_links.yml")[resource].collect do |link|
  active = (eval(link.last) == request.path) ? "active" : ""
  path = link.last.empty? ? "#" : eval(link.last)

  content_tag(:li, link_to(link.first, path), class: active)
end.join.html_safe
```

And I want to test if the method is building the links in the right way. I can't discover how to do the stubs for the YAML.load_file("config/admin_links.yml")[resource] to output an Hash for the collect method to work on.

I have already tested using

```
hash_link = {"Dashboard"=>"admin_dashboard_path", "Configurações"=>""}
allow_any_instance_of(YAML).to receive(:load_file).with(["test"]).and_return(hash_link)

u = YAML
allow(u).to receive_message_chain(:load_file, :[] ,:collect)
```

But no success so far. How i'm supposed to do the mock so "YAML.load_file("config/admin_links.yml")[resource]" returns "{"Dashboard"=>"admin_dashboard_path", "Configurações"=>""" so the method collect can work on the variable?

tnx,

Answer (score 1):

`load_file` is a class method of `YAML`, not an instance method, so you can stub it with `allow(YAML).to receive(:load_file).and_return(hash_link)`.

Comment: 'it "testing" do                            
    allow(YAML).to receive(:load_file).and_return(hash_link)
    allow_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Request).to receive(:path).and_return("/admin/Dashboard")
    
    build_links("test")    
  end'

It fails and gives the following Rspec error:

Failure/Error: build_links("test")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I guess it is not propagating the stub for the collect method. But I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: It sounds like the hash does not contain the key you're looking for. Change `[key]` to `fetch(key)` to get a more useful failure message.

Comment: Also, stubbing `ActionDispatch::Request` shouldn't be necessary, but perhaps that's a discussion for later.

Answer (score 0):

Rspec will often teach you to partition methods for easy stubbing. In this case, extract the reading of the YAML file and you can stub the results very simply.

```
class MyClass
  def self.admin_links
    YAML.load_file("config/admin_links.yml")
  end

  def build_links(resource)
    self.class.admin_links[resource].collect do |link|
       # ...
    end
  end
end

allow(MyClass).to receive_message(:admin_links).and_return(hash_link)
```

Comment: Be wary of this approach: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/don-t-stub-the-system-under-test